# Como alterar a cor do fundo de uma tabela html com javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma tabela que vai ser listada com vários valores, eu quero que quando o campo  tiver o valor "D" ele fique com o background vermelho, e quando o resultado for "A", ele fique verde. Segue o exemplo de como estou tentando fazer mais não está dando certo.
Ficarei grato se alguém poder me ajudar.

```js
var fundo = document.getElementById('td').value;

if (fundo == 'D') {
  fundo.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
  fundo.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Sitiação</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td>Felipe</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td>Carlos</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0003</td>
    <td>Amanada</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeira coisa que notei é que o seu objetivo é separar algumas células de uma tabela e a colorir segundo o critério cujo é a situação atribuída a uma pessoa.

Acontece que da forma que aborda o problema não há a possibilidade prática de distinguir entre as células da sua tabela.

Veja o seu código refatorado.

```js
//Seleciona todos os elementos <td> do documento.
let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

//Para cada elemento <td>...
tds.forEach((td) => {
  //...Se texto for "D" colore em vermelho caso contrário colore em verde.
  td.style.backgroundColor = (td.innerText == 'D') ? "red" : "green";
});
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Situação</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td>Felipe</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td>Carlos</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0003</td>
    <td>Amanada</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Inicialmente usei o método [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), que retorna uma lista de elementos presentes no documento dado um seletor, junto do seletor `td` para obter todas células de tabela e em seguida iterei por essa lista de células as colorido.

Veja que todas as células da tabela estão coloridas em verde exceto a célula cujo o texto é `"D"` pois o programa não consegue distinguir uma célula contento o nome de uma célula contento a nota de uma célula contento a identificação.

O que precisa fazer é adicionar uma informação a determinado grupo de células para que essa informação possa ser detectada e o auxiliar ao separar as células que devem ser coloridas das que não devem ser coloridas.

Essa informação pode ser conferida no próprio elemento *HTML* através da propriedade [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) que nada mais é que uma lista das classes de um elemento, separada por espaços. As Classes permitem ao *CSS* e ao *Javascript* selecionar e acessar elementos específicos através dos seletores de classe ou funções como o método DOM [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Veja o exemplo:

```js
//Seleciona apenas os elementos <td> do documento cujo a classe é nota.
let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td[class='nota']");

//Agora itera apenas pelos elementos cujo a classe é nota.
tds.forEach((td) => {
  td.style.backgroundColor = (td.innerText == 'D') ? "red" : "green";
});
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Situação</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td>Felipe</td>
    <td class="nota">A</td><!--Atribui a classe nota a essa célula-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td>Carlos</td>
    <td class="nota">D</td><!--Atribui a classe nota a essa célula-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0003</td>
    <td>Amanada</td>
    <td class="nota">A</td><!--Atribui a classe nota a essa célula-->
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Dessa forma daria certo, mais não tenho como atribuir uma classe porque estou montando a tabela direto com o PHP pegando os dados do banco através de um select. Mesmo assim obrigado, a primeira resposta se adapta exatamente com o meu cenário.

Answer (score 0):

Olá veja se adicionando uma classe vc consegue fazer, segue um exemplo:

```
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById('td');
   element.classList.add("classeComFundoVermelho");
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma daria certo, mais não tenho como atribuir uma classe porque estou montando a tabela direto com o PHP pegando os dados do banco através de um select. Mesmo assim obrigado, a primeira resposta se adapta exatamente com o meu cenário.